# Java. Abstract class child counter listener

Tags: java

I have n child classes inherit from Parent. I need to count all child objects and when all will be done trigger listener. Unfortunately I'm getting an errors: "Static member 'childCountListener' accessed via instance reference" and "'this' cannot be referenced form a static context". I know I cannot use "this" because I don't have object of this class but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Parent:

```
public abstract class Parent {

protected static int childCount = 0;
private static ChildCountListener childCountListener;

public Parent() {
    // (...)
    incrementChildCount();
}

public void doSomething() {
    // (...)
    decrementChildCount();
}

public static int getChildCount() {
    return childCount;
}

private void incrementChildCount() {
    childCount++;
}

private void decrementChildCount() {
    childCount--;

    if (childCount < 1) {
        childCountListener.allDone();
    }
}

public static void addChildCountListener(ChildCountListener childCountListener) {
    this.childCountListener = childCountListener;
    // Static member 'childCountListener' accessed via instance reference
    // 'this' cannot be referenced form a static context
}

public interface ChildCountListener {
    void allDone();
}
}
```

Comment: Take out the `this` keyword. `this` refers to the current instance, and static methods are not instance based; it doesn't know which instance to refer to. You don't need `this`. If you're trying to prevent shadowing, do `Parent.childCountListener = ...` instead of `this.childCountListener = ...`

Comment: "Variable 'childCountListener' is assigned to itself"

Comment: I edited my comment soon after. To prevent shadowing, read my comment. You get that warning when you assign a variable to the same variable

Comment: Hahah, thanks. This "error" made my day.

Comment: Parenthetically, you should note that your code is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `this` from `addChildCountListener`

```
public static void addChildCountListener(ChildCountListener childCountListener) {
    Parent.childCountListener = childCountListener;
}
```

or

```
public static void addChildCountListener(ChildCountListener aChildCountListener) {
    childCountListener = aChildCountListener;
}
```